# mysql, запросы многие ко многим

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

Есть три таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`iduser` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
`idproject` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nameproj` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`date_of_creation` DATE NOT NULL,
`date_update` DATE NOT NULL,
`type_pr` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idproject`)

CREATE TABLE `user_project` (
`idus` INT NOT NULL,
`idpr` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idus`, `idpr`),
FOREIGN KEY (`idus`)
REFERENCES `user` (`iduser`)
FOREIGN KEY (`idpr`)
REFERENCES `project` (`idproject`)
```

И можно ли как-то посчитать количество созданных проектов, созданных в рамках квартала без использования входных параметров по дате? Только силами sql?

Comment: *количество созданных проектов, созданных в рамках квартала без использования входных параметров по дате* Нет. SQL сервер неспособен догадаться, для какого квартала нужны данные. Но вот посчитать для каждого из кварталов, для которых есть записи (хоть вместе, хоть по отдельности) - это запросто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно использовать встроенную функцию

```
select QUARTER(NOW()) as kvartal ;
```

Примерный запрос

```
select count(user_project.idpr), QUARTER(project.date_of_creation) as qart
from project, user_project
where project.idproject=user_project.idpr
group by qart
```